# Automating outlook using webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the process of moving mails from **sent items** to other folders based on the subject of mail.is it possible using webdriver to automate this?I have automated sending mails and also attachments.just want to move the  ail from sent items folder.if anyone having any idea about it?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the filters built into Outlook?  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-c24f5dea-9465-4df4-ad17-a50704d66c59

Comment: you mean the rules right?Yes i can use filters..but was just thinking if we can automate this using webdriver so asked this question

Comment: So, pretty much you can automate almost everything if it's about a web page. But it's going to be a wasted effort though if you are thinking it's going to do this job more efficiently for you. Rules would any day be better. But, if it's just about practice, Go Ahead!

Comment: Hmm ya.But how can we do it?